# Abstract class inheriting from non-abstract in .NET?

Tags: .net, templates, generics, inheritance, abstract-class

I'd like to know if a subclass of a concrete (that is, not abstract) class can be abstract or not. In a fictitious example:

```
public class HistoricallyManaged<SpecificType> 
  { // code to manage history }

public abstract class ComputationalNode<SpecificType>: HistoricallyManaged<SpecificType>
  { // common methods implemented, but some left to concrete classes }

public class Formula<SpecificType>: ComputationalNode<SpecificType> 
  { // code to manage common formula behavior like checking if parameters have been calculated }

public class Variable<SpecificType>: ComputationalNode<SpecificType>  
 { // code to manage common variable behavior like persisting values }

// usage example
public class SomeOtherClass {
  private Formula<int> intFormula;
  private Formula<double> doubleFormula;
  private Variable<int> intVar;
  private Variable<double> doubleVar;
}
```

In the example above I want to forbide instantiating **ComputationalNode** or using template binding to make types like **ComputationalNode**, however I do want to allow declaring **HistoricallyManaged** and other types, so higher in the hierarchy instantiation would have to be possible, but not at middle level.

Thanks for your valued help.

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Comment: So, does it compile? Does it run? Surely that would give you the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can. `object` is not `abstract` (although IMO it should be), so **every** `abstract class` is actually an example of this:

```
abstract class Foo {} // tada! - note this is implicitly : object
```

You would need to further subclass it as non-`abstract` before you could create an instance of it, though.

But to be explicit:

```
class Foo {} // fine
abstract class Bar : Foo {} // fine
class Blap : Bar {} // fine
```